# HortonWorks Ambari 1.7.0 selects wrong HDP stack

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, ambari

I'm trying to setup a 6 node HDP 2.2 cluster using Ambari 1.7.0. After a hack (by adding 'export PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.6' to ambari-agent/ambari-enh) to get the ambari-agent daemon running on the agent nodes, I'm able to register target hosts.

However, I encounter a horrible problem during the 'Deploy' step. It seems that although I've selected the HDP 2.2 stack, HDP 2.0.6 is still selected.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/HDFS/package/scripts/datanode.py", line 21, in <module>
from hdfs_datanode import datanode
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/HDFS/package/scripts/hdfs_datanode.py", line 21, in <module>
from resource_management.libraries.functions.dfs_datanode_helper import handle_dfs_data_dir
ImportError: No module named dfs_datanode_helper
```

And the ambari-agent.log contains the following:

```
INFO 2015-02-06 00:11:47,707 PythonExecutor.py:118 - Result: 
 {'structuredOut': {}, 
  'stdout': '2015-02-06 00:11:47,687 - Error while executing command
   \'status\':\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", 
 line 123, in execute\n  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/GANGLIA/package/scripts/ganglia_monitor.py", 
 line 63, in status\n    
 raise ComponentIsNotRunning()\nComponentIsNotRunning', 
      'stderr': '2015-02-06 00:11:47,687 - Error while executing command
     \'status\':\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  
          File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", 
          line 123, in execute\n  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/GANGLIA/package/scripts/ganglia_monitor.py", line 63, in status\n    
          raise ComponentIsNotRunning()\nComponentIsNotRunning', 'exitcode': 1}
```

Question: Why is HDP 2.0.6 being installed even if I've selected HDP 2.2?

My environment info: 
CentOS 6.6, HortonWorks Ambari 1.7.0, HDP-2.2, HDP-UTILS-1.1

Repos:
HDP-2.2                                                                                                                                                                 HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20                                                                                                                                                      Updates-ambari-1.7.0                                                                                                                                                    ambari-1.x

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour. Ambari Stacks can inherit from previous versions. So in your case HDFS, for Stack 2.2, inherits from the Stack version 2.1, which also inherits from version 2.0.6.

This is defined here : https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/release-1.7.0/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/metainfo.xml

Now, back to the real issue, Ganglia is simply not running. The error you see is raised on the status check for the Ganglia service. I would start there.